# Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in Test.ovpn:1: ÿþc (2.4.9)

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in Test.ovpn:1: ÿþc (2.4.9)
Use --help for more information.
```

I am quite confused with this error with my `ovpn` file... I have looked into this issue and the issue should be listed after the `Test.ovpn:1`, however, my `ovpn` file has no traces of the word `ÿþc`. What could this mean? What can I do to fix it?

Test.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp4-client
remote <IP> 
port <Port>
tls-client
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1
remote-cert-tls server
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\Test.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\Test.key"

cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
```

---

<sub>The `<IP>` and `<Port>` are the actual ports in the ovpn file...</sub>

Comment: did you find a solution?